# ls command hangs after I pause the destination folder

Tags: linux, redhat, mount, ls

I have two instances of RHEL 7 Linux, machine 1 and machine 2. Machine 2 has a folder that is mounted to a remote folder from machine 1. It is done with command: `mount -t cifs -o user=aaa,pass=password //machine 1's ip/SrcFolder/`. This works fine but however when I pause machine 1 then if I issue a command such as `ls` it would hang in machine 2. If I unpause machine 1 then everything is back to normal. I am suspecting that whatever the daemon running mount is hold on to the file system resource which prevent other i/o operation to complete? Is there a way so the client can detect right away?

Comment: What do you mean by "pause machine 1"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the two machines are virtual instances sitting in a same physical box. I can pause the vm with vm manager tool.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to access files on the machine when it is paused, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I am not trying to access file on the machine that is paused rather I am interested in how I can ensure commands like ls still function properly when the mounted drive is not available. Is there something I can pass on to the mount command to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not trying to access file on the machine that is paused

Actually, you are... Any command that accesses the file system, i.e. 'ls' will give you trouble if the remote system is no longer available. When Machine1 is paused, can you still ping it successfully?

I hope this helps